# Wordpress Multisite Not Working after Migration to New Server

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress Multisite which was working fine until I migrated the instance over to a new physical server.

The funny thing is that The instance itself is fine: I can get to everything except one of the sites. I cannot get to it's Admin section either, both the individual site and it's admin section come up as blank white pages. But none of my other sites do which I find rather weird.

It's not a database connection issue. I don't believe it's an .htaccess issue because i just copied over the same .htaccess file from the server that the whole instance was previously working on.

The only thing I can think of is that the Drive that Wordpress sits on is now different (D: now as opposed to E:).

I have mod_rewrite enabled and like I said all the other individual sites are working along with their individual admins.

I moved from Windows 2003 server to a Windows 2008 server and they are both on Apache Web Server.

Anyone else have the same problem or know of a way to remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blank white page is a php error.

Check your error logs. That one site is using a plugin or theme with a conflict.